# Borel measurability of a subset of a product space

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, product-space

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces and let $\mathcal B_X$ and $\mathcal B_Y$ be their respective Borel $\sigma$-algebras.

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$ and let $\mathcal B^*_X$ be the $\mu$-completion of $\mathcal B_X$.

If $E$ belongs to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B^*_X\otimes\mathcal B_Y$, does there exist a $\mu$-null set $A$ in $\mathcal B_X$ such that $E\cup(A\times Y)\in\mathcal B_X\otimes\mathcal B_Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the collection of $E\in\mathcal{B}_X^*\otimes \mathcal{B}_Y$ for which:

1. There exists $A\subseteq X$ null with $E\cup (A\times Y)\in\mathcal{B}_X\otimes\mathcal{B}_Y$.
2. There exists $A\subseteq X$ null with $E\setminus (A\times Y)\in\mathcal{B}_X\otimes\mathcal{B}_Y$.

Then it suffices to show that $\mathscr{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the rectangles $A\times B$, $A\in\mathcal{B}_X^*$, $B\in\mathcal{B}_Y$.

For rectangles, use the fact that we can approximate, both on the inside and the outside, elements of $\mathcal{B}_X^*$ by elements of $\mathcal{B}_X$.

For countable unions, property 1. is easy to deal with. For 2., suppose $E_n\in\mathscr{C}$, and for each $n$ choose $A_n$ satisfying $2$. Then $\bigcup_m A_m$ is null in $\mathcal{B}_X$ and
$$\bigg(\bigcup_n E_n\bigg)\setminus\bigg(\bigg(\bigcup_m A_m\bigg)\times Y\bigg)=\bigcup_n\bigg(E_n\setminus \bigg(\bigcup_m \big(A_m\times Y\big)\bigg)\bigg)$$

For a given $n$, $E_n\setminus\big(\bigcup_m (A_m\times Y)\big)=\big(E_n\setminus(A_n\times Y)\big)\setminus\big(\bigcup_m(A_m\times Y)\big)$, which belongs to $\mathcal{B}_X\otimes\mathcal{B}_Y$, so their union also belongs to it.

For complements, given $E\in\mathscr{C}$, use property 1. for $E$ to obtain property 2. for $E^c$ and vice-versa, so $E^c\in\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for this. Am I correct that it remains to show that $\mathcal C$ is closed under countable intersections?

Comment: @mo15 This is not necessary, in general, since any class of sets which is closed under countable unions and complements is closed under countable intersections (because $\bigcap_n A_n=\left(\bigcup_n A_n^c\right)^c$), but you should mention this, if your definition of $\sigma$-algebra has this condition as well.

Comment: You should probably add that the null sets $A $ in properties 1. and 2. should be Borel. Up to that: nice answer!

Comment: @Luiz. I see. In this case the answer seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @PhoemueX. I do not see why the null sets should be added to properties 1 and 2.

Comment: @mo15: For example, the answer uses that $E_n\setminus\big(\bigcup_m (A_m\times Y)\big)=\big(E_n\setminus(A_n\times Y)\big)\setminus\big(\bigcup_m(A_m\times Y)\big)$ is Borel. This uses that $\big(E_n\setminus(A_n\times Y)\big)$ is Borel (ok) and that $\big(\bigcup_m(A_m\times Y)\big)$ is Borel (not ok, without requiring that in conditions 1. and 2.). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PhoemueX: But we have $A_m\times Y\in\mathcal B_X\otimes\mathcal B_Y$ for each $m$, and so $\bigcup_m(A_m\times Y)\in\mathcal B_X\otimes\mathcal B_Y$...

Comment: @mo15: Why? Note that $A_m $ is a null-set, not necessarily a **Borel** null-set. All I am saying is that we should require this to be be the case, in conditions 1. And 2. The rest of the proof can stay as it is, of course.

Comment: @PhoemueX: He is defining (as fas as I can see) $A_m$ as a $\mu$-null set, and note that $\mu$ is a Borel measure.